# Calculate working days between dates then allocate to calendar months with additional logic

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have been trying to crack this for a few days and as I am an excel intermediate at best. And I am struggling.

Essentially I have 3 columns of data: One with hours of leave taken, the next column with start date and the final column with end date.

I need to be able to correctly analyse and allocate the number of working days per calendar month. This will then be "summarized" on a summary page. I have found a method that gets me close, extremely close (thanks to another stackoverflow post). Below is the formula that gets me close:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(IF($W1592="",TODAY(),$W1592),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(AB$3&"-17"),0))-MAX($V1592,DATEVALUE(AB$3&"-17"))+1)
```

The issue is that some of the leave taken is less than 1 full day. Sometimes it may only be 2.5 hours. I need the formula to state that, if the leave start date and end date are in the same month, then return the calculation of leave hours taken/7.5 (=$U4/7.5)

I have tried a few different ways but nothing quite works. Any assistance is appreciated.

[Snip of worksheet showing data and how it should be allocated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNCmP.jpg)

Comment: just to get this correctly... the first column is divided by 7.5 (hours per day). then this will be split up from the first day (so technically no end-date is needed)... so 15h starting on August 31st would show 1 at August and 1 in September column... 20 would show 1 at August and 1d and 5h on september???

Comment: Hi Dirk, The above is correct. The first column is the hours taken. When it spans more then 2 working days the trend/norm is only full days are taken. The easiest solution I could think was if the calendar months don't match then return the number of working days between the dates as it would be too difficult to determine partial hours.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
A2:C9 = <your sample data>
```

I put :

```
L1 = Sep-2017
M1 = Oct-2017
N1 = Nov-2017
O1 = Dec-2017
P1 = Jan-2018
Q1 = Feb-2018
R1 = Mar-2018
S1 = Apr-2018
T1 = May-2018
U1 = Jun-2018
V1 = Jul-2018
W1 = Aug-2018
X1 = Sep-2018
Y1 = Oct-2018

*all in proper excel date format

L2

=IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($B2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($B2)),AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($C2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($C2))),$A2/7.5,IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($B2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($B2)),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2)),EOMONTH($B2,0)-$B2,IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($C2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($C2)),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2)),DAY($C2),IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)<>MONTH($C2),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2),MONTH(L$1)<>MONTH($B2)),AND(L$1>$B2,L$1<$C2)),DAY(EOMONTH(L$1,0)),""))))
```

and drag it until Y9

lastly,

```
L10   =SUM(L2:L9)
```

drag it until Y10.

So your "number of working days per calendar month" will be in L10:Y10 .

I think this should get you there. Please comment if you need assistance. (:

+----------[algo info]-----------+

Breakdown if L2 :

r=a=b

```
=IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($B2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($B2)),AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($C2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($C2))),$A2/7.5,"")
```

r=a, a!=b

```
=IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($B2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($B2)),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2)),EOMONTH($B2,0)-$B2,"")
```

r=b, a!=b

```
=IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)=MONTH($C2),YEAR(L$1)=YEAR($C2)),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2)),DAY($C2),"")
```

r!=a!=b

```
=IF(AND(AND(MONTH(L$1)<>MONTH($C2),MONTH($B2)<>MONTH($C2),MONTH(L$1)<>MONTH($B2)),AND(L$1>$B2,L$1<$C2)),DAY(EOMONTH(L$1,0)),"")
```

+-------[previous post - archived]-------+

referring to : " if the leave start date and end date are in the same month, then return the calculation of leave hours taken/7.5 (=$U4/7.5)"

```
=if(month(<startDate>)=month(<endDate>), $U4/7.5, <yourOriginalFormula>)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this, I have tried this combo and it doesn't seem to work. The issue seems to be it get's confused with so many nested formula's and returns calendar days not working days. If you have any further idea's I would love to hear them!

Comment: A question.. eg.. for data 112.5 hours from Jan 1 to Jan 22.. how do I know the "0.5" hours is at Jan 1 or Jan 22nd?

Comment: A working day is 7.5 hours so the above is a total of 15 full days. The pattern of behaviour is that if the leave spans 2 or more days, there will be no partial days. As the above falls in the same calendar month we do not need to allocate where a partial day falls. Ideally if the leave spans across more than 1 calendar month than it needs to only return the network days between the dates and allocate them accordingly.